# HBase rest service did not respond in a secure cluster

Tags: java, rest, hbase

HBase Version 1.1.5 
OS - Windows

I have enabled HBase rest service with SSL and Proxy.

When accessing HBase rest url,

https://machine1:8082/version/cluster

it returns nothing and keep on loading.

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.keytab.file</name>
  <value>thrift.keytab</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>Principal</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.support.proxyuser</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.authentication.type</name>
  <value>kerberos</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>HTTP/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
  <value>http.keytab</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.ssl.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.ssl.keystore.store</name>
  <value>keystore</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.ssl.keystore.password</name>
  <value>pass</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.ssl.keystore.keypassword</name>
  <value>keypass</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rest.port</name>
  <value>8082</value>
</property>
```

Few times later, logs shows

```
Unavailable
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedEception: Failed after attempts=14, exceptions:
Mon Oct 10 12:55:21 IST 2016, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1476084308042, pause=1000, retries=14}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Call to machine2/192.168.60.4:60000 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to machine2/192.168.60.4:60000 is closing. Call id=66, waitTime=13088
```

Do i miss anything?

Any help would be appreciated.